# Compiled File is missing (macOS)

Tags: macos, compile

I was just coding in C language on my macOS and tried to compile my file. Before I could save it (it"s just stupid, I know.. I always do backups.. but not this time)..well.. I compiled it and my code was just gone. The .c file is gone and now I have to start coding again..

I wonder if you know a method to retrieve my file. Maybe it's just hidden or something.

Comment: Have you saved your file in dropbox, gmail, google drive or somewhere in the web?

Comment: I wish I had. But I haven't. It was in the middle of the night, I was just so tired.. shut happends when u don't sleep :(

Comment: The executables in mac os have the same extensions (.c)?

Comment: it's an executable unix data, it executes the program i coded, but it has no .c end